# Interlocked.increment still not solving value missing problems

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm studying C# right now and currently learning threading.

Here is a simple example to adding 1 to a variable multiple times within different threads.

The book suggested I can use `Interlocked.increment(ref number)` to replace the number `+= 1` within the `AddOne` method, therefore the value will be locked until it's updated within the thread. So the output will be `1000, 2000, ..... 10000` as expected. But My output is still `999, 1999, 2999, ...... 9999`.

Only after I uncomment the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` line will the output be correct but even without the `Interlocked` been used.

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myNum n = new myNum();

    for (int i = 0;i<10; Interlocked.Increment(ref i))
    {
        for(int a =1;a<=1000; Interlocked.Increment(ref a))
        {
            Thread t = new Thread( new ThreadStart( n.AddOne));
            t.Start();
        }

        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(n.number);
    }
}

class myNum
{            
    public int number = 0;

    public void AddOne()
    {
        //number += 1;
        Interlocked.Increment(ref number);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It a bit strange for me what you trying to achieve with this code. You are using `Interlocked.Increment` everywhere without explicit needs for it.

`Interlocked.Increment` required for access to values which can be accessed from different threads. In your code it is only `number`, so you don't require it for `i` and `a`, just use as usually `i++` and `a++`

The problem you are asking for is that you just don't wait for all threads you started are completed its job. Take a look to [Thread.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) method. You have to wait while **all** of threads you are started completes its work.

In this simple test you are done with `Thread.Sleep(1000);` you do similar wait but its not correct to assume that all threads are complete in 1000 ms, so just use `Thread.Join()` for that.

If you modify your `AddOne()` method so it starts to executes longer (e.g. add `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to it) you'll notice that `Thread.Sleep(1000);` doesn't help any more.

I'll suggest to read more about [ThreadPool vs Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kac2kdh.aspx). Also take a look to [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en)

Comment: Actually, Thread.Sleep(1000) would still work fine if you do a Thread.Sleep(10) in AddOne() because 10 << 1000.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, the use of Interlocked.Increment in the for loop is what's the sample code in the book, which I think is not necessary either..... The t.join(); is very useful it waits the thread until it finishes. I will do more reading as you suggested. Cheers!

Comment: @Fantius, it depends, since starting 10000 threads at once can overwhelm system, but actually you are right on most modern systems it almost not noticeable. I'll correct, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are printing out the value before all of the threads have finished executing.  You need to join all of the threads before printing.

```
for(int a = 0; a < 1000; a++)
  {
    t[a].Join();
  }
```

You'll need to store the threads in an array or list.  Also, you don't need the interlocked instruction in any of the for loops.  They all run in only one thread (the main thread).  Only the code in AddOne runs in multiple threads and hence needs to by synchronized.